# Filtrar csv mediante request.get(url)

Tags: json, url

a ver si me podeis hechar una mano.

Estaba intentando realizar un ejemplo de filtrado que plantean en la propia web: https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/es/desenvolupadors#CSV, lo hago de la siguiente forma y no se que error estoy cometiendo:

```
import json
import requests
url='https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/api/action/datastore_search? 
resource_id=21f7a4df-2e73-45f8-8c6d-0b3db8c21527&limit=5&q= 
{%22INVENTARI_CARRER%22:%22%Mallorca%%22}' 

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
data
```

Obteniendo lo siguiente:
      [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El problema es que en 'records' donde se supone que tenía que aparecer la información filtrada aparece vacío.

Aquí dejo el enlace donde aparece el ejemplo planteados por ellos con la info filtrada:
https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=21f7a4df-2e73-45f8-8c6d-0b3db8c21527&limit=5&q={%22INVENTARI_CARRER%22:%22%Mallorca%%22}

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el parámetro de la query tienes que escapar las comillas:

```js
const url = 'https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=21f7a4df-2e73-45f8-8c6d-0b3db8c21527&limit=5&q={"INVENTARI_CARRER":"Mallorca"}'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    const d = fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Utilizando fetch API me devuelve el resultado correcto.